# Bootstrap 5 alter button text color of open accordion with css

Tags: button, accordion, bootstrap-5, textcolor

I want to change the appearance (color) of the text inside the div inside the button when the accordion is open but not being hovered on. I have been able to alter the color of the text on hover when the accordion is open, but once I am no longer hovering on the text and the accordion is open, the text color goes grey again rather than staying red. I am asking for help to maintain the color of the text within the button when the accordion panel is open, but not being hovered on. I.E. When hovered on and accordion is open, color is a dark red, when accordion is open, but not hovered on, I want it to remain dark red. When the accordion is collapsed, I want the text to be grey. the hover title (div.btn_inner-silver)text color when the accordion panel is open the color of the text as it appears when hovered on.

**How it appears when closed**

[image]

**How text appears when on hover**

[image]

**How it appears when uncollapsed/open**

[image]

**How I want it to appear when open/uncollapsed**

[image]

**HTML MARK UP**

```html
<div class="accordion" id="acrd_sidebar1-14">
<!--   DATE/TIME   -->
<div class="accordion-item">
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="hdr_timestamp1-14">
   <button type="button" aria-expanded="true" data-mdb-toggle="collapse" data-mdb-target="#collapsetimestamp1-14" aria-controls="collapsetimestamp1-14" class="accordion-button pd_all8 btn_sidebar-brand">
      <div class="btn_inner-silver" >
         Date + Time
      </div>
   </button>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```css
.btn_inner-silver {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver!important;
    background: white;
    text-align: center!important;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: silver;
}

.btn_inner-silver:hover {
    color: #981e21;
}

.btn_inner-silver collapsed {
    color: #981e21;
}

h2.accordion-header button.accordion-button.btn_sidebar-brand div.btn_inner-silver collapsed:focus {
    color: pink!important;
}
```

**SUMMARY of QUESTION**

How do I *keep the color of the **text red** when the **selected accordion panel** is **open***/uncollapsed?

I have tried a number of things, but am unable to target the open state. I've googled galore, sifted through the stack, experimented and failed repeatedly. Hoping for help. I am a newb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it looks like your missing the `.` in front of `collapsed` in the rule below.

```css
.btn_inner-silver collapsed {
    color: #981e21;
}
```

Secondly, in the [Accordion example here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/#example), they are using the [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) `:not()` to target the element that does not have the `.collapsed` class.

So it would look something like this I think for you:

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) .btn_inner-silver{
    color: #981e21;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and damn my dyslexia -- thanks and happy New Years !